# SQL Server 2008 r2, trouble casting int to decimal

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to do what seems like a basic cast of int to decimal, and it's not working. I've experimented with performing the cast before the insert, no better. I want to use the decimal values to show percentage change. The code is below, along with output. Any help would be great..

```
DECLARE @tblVar TABLE (LatestCount INT, PriorCount INT, 
                       PctChgLatestVsPrior DECIMAL, PctChgLatestVsAvg DECIMAL)

DECLARE @tbl CHAR(30)
DECLARE @dte DATE
DECLARE @dte2 DATE
DECLARE @latestCount INT
DECLARE @priorCount INT
DECLARE @avgAllCounts INT

SET @tbl = 'tblDailyPricingAndVol'
SET @dte = '5/8/12'
SET @dte2 = '5/7/12'

EXEC spAvgOfCountByDateAddedByTable @tbl, @avg = @avgAllCounts OUTPUT
EXEC spCountOfDateAddedByTableAndDate @tbl, @dte, @count = @latestCount OUTPUT
EXEC spCountOfDateAddedByTableAndDate @tbl, @dte2, @count = @priorCount OUTPUT

INSERT INTO @tblVar 
VALUES (@latestCount, @priorCount, 
    CAST((@latestCount-@priorCount) AS DECIMAL)/CAST(@priorCount AS DECIMAL), 
    CAST((@latestCount-@avgAllCounts) AS DECIMAL)/CAST(@avgAllCounts AS DECIMAL))

SELECT * FROM @tblVar
```

Output:

```
19548
7107
8483

LatestCount PriorCount  PctChgLatestVsPrior PctChgLatestVsAvg
7107        8483        0                   -1
```

Comment: "it's not working" is not a great description of the actual issue. **What** is not working? Exactly?

Comment: The portion of the comment preceeding "it's not working." The cast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to give decimal scale/precision

See here: [Decimal and Numeric problems when you don't specify precision and scale](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/decimal-and-numeric-problems-when-you-do)

Some examples: DECIMAL(30,10)  or DECIMAL(20)

See more in Books On Line http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

Comment: +1 OP should try this: `SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL, 3.567);` and read this (which applies equally to `DECIMAL` of course): https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: Thanks... I have very similar code in a simple select statement and it works as I expected, perhaps it performs differently in a stored procedure.